# Understanding proof of Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to understand proof of the mentioned theorem. So let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ be injective maps. Then there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$. I tried to understand following steps, and after intuitive picture of the proof given in Charles Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis, I confused in one step.

(1) If $f(A)=B$, then $f$ is a required bijection from $A$ to $B$; similarly if $g(B)=A$ then $g$ is a required bijection.

(2) Thus, **assume that** $f(A)<B$ (proper subset) and $g(B)<A$.

(3) Using injectivity of $f$ and $g$, along with (2), we can obtain two **strictly decreasing** sequences of subsets: one in $A$ and other in $B$:

$$A > g(B) > gf(A) > gfg(B) > gfgf(A) > \cdots $$
and 
$$B>f(A) > fg(B) > fgf(A) >fgfg(B) >  \cdots $$

(4) Think of set $A$ and $B$ as pictorially represented as rings, and all above subsets as proper subrings.

Then the key step (observation) is

- annulus $A\setminus g(B)$ is bijection with annulus $f(A)\setminus fg(B)$ (under $f$) and
- annulus $B\setminus f(A)$ is in bijection with $g(B)\setminus gf(A)$ (under $g$.

(5) Once (4) is complete, ignore first two anuli in above two series; argue in similar way for next two.

**Q.** The above sequence of sets is **countable** strictly decreasing sequence of subsets of $A$ and of $B$. But we do not know, whether given $x\in A$, it will lie in some annuli or not. Thus, it seems that above bijections is incomplete; something is remained in the proof. How should I complete the proof?

Comment: That sounds pretty rough. I'm familiar enough with the _usual_ proof, but steps 4 and 5 of what you have quoted do not make much sense to me. Do you think [Wikipedia's proof sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) looks clearer?

Comment: Besides being rough, at a glance this argument seems to be assuming that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(gf)^n(A)=\emptyset$ (and analogously for the $B$ side) - that is, that every element of $A$ shows up in some annulus. But that's not true in general. We need to separately observe that the set of elements of $A$ not in any $A$-annulus is in bijection with the set of elements of $B$ not in any $B$-annulus.  I'm not a fan of this write-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very clear write-up, and it's missing a key step. Here's how I would phrase it (although actually I prefer a different argument entirely):

- First, we change notation a bit to make things easier to write: we'll let $S_i$ denote the $i$th annulus of $A$ (so $S_0=A\setminus g(B), S_1=g(B)\setminus gf(A),$ etc.) and $T_i$ denote the $i$th annulus of $B$ (so $T_0=B\setminus f(A), T_1=f(A)\setminus fg(B)$, etc.).
- Next we show that $S_{2n}\equiv T_{2n+1}$ and $T_{2n}\equiv S_{2n+1}$ for each $n$ (e.g. $S_0$ is in bijection with $T_1$, $S_1$ is in bijection with $T_0$, $S_2$ is in bijection with $T_3$, $S_3$ is in bijection with $T_2$, etc.).
- **But we're not done yet** (and this is the step Pugh omits): why need we have $A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}S_i$ (and similarly for $B$)? Indeed this doesn't need to hold in general (suppose there is some $a\in A$ such that $gf(a)=a$ ...). So we *also* have to consider the "bad sets" $$X=A\setminus(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n)\quad\mbox{and}\quad Y=B\setminus (\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}T_n).$$ Now you need to **show that $f$ is a bijection between $X$ and $Y$**. Once you've done that, you'll be done: you'll have partitioned $A$ into one family of sets, $B$ into another family of sets, and "paired up" those families such that bijections exist appropriately.