# Questions about the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

The following is the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem in Real Analysis with Real Applications by Donsig and Davidson p.$63$:

[image]

There are certain parts of the proof that I'm having trouble understanding. When I try drawing a diagram using Figure $2.6$ as a reference, for example, I'm unable to complete the diagram using a finite number of points. That is, using Figure $2.6$ I replaced the "ellipsis block" in both $A$ and $B$ by $A_{4}$ and $B_{4}$. Then I assigned exactly one point to each of $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},A_{4},$ and $A_{5}$. I repeated the process with $B$ and assigned exactly one point to each $B_{1},B_{2},B_{3},B_{4},$ and $B_{5}$. But then applying the recursive process in the given proof, I can't apply the function $f$ to $A_{4}$ since this would imply the existence of some subset $B_{5}$ of $B$ which doesn't exist in the diagram that I've constructed. I'd like to know where I'm going wrong or what important assumption I'm missing.

Also, I'm unsure what $(fg)^{i-1}$ is supposed to represent. Is it supposed to be some sort of composite function made up of both $f$ and $g$, raised to the power $i-1$?

Comment: There are other proofs. Search this site. Caution: It is also called the Cantor-Bernstein or Schroeder-Cantor-Bernstein theorem. There is one proof which I gave as an Answer on this site, which can also be found in Introduction To Topology And Modern Analysis, by Simmons, which is the simplest proof I know of.

Comment: @Daniel: Don't forget the Cantor–Schroeder–Bernstein. And the variations of Schröder, Schroder, and Schroeder as well.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Which proof does Simmons use? Is it the one that constructs $C_0:=A\setminus g[B],\,C_{n+1}:=g[f[C_n]],\,C:=\bigcup_{n\ge0}C_n$?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320794/understanding-proof-of-schroeder-bernstein-theorem?

Comment: @J.G. It is the proof in Wikipedia (attributed to Julius Konig) but I think Simmons' presentation is clearer.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Fair enough. The one I had in mind is my personal favourite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an infinite process, we have $B_1=B\setminus f(A)$, then 
$$A_1=g(B_1),\ B_2=f(A_1),\ A_2=g(B_2),\ \dots, B_5=f(A_4),\ A_5=g(B_5),\ \dots$$
Yes, $(fg)^{i-1}$ is the $i-1$-fold composition of the composite $fg$ with itself. If $i-1=0$, we mean the identity function.

Comment: Since the process is infinite and the subsets $A_{n}$ and $B_{n}$ are disjoint, does that necessarily mean that $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets?

Comment: No, they can also be empty. Think e.g. when $f$ is bijection and $g=f^{-1}$.

Comment: If $B \setminus f(A) = \emptyset$ then $A$ and $B$ can have any cardinality.

Comment: If $B \setminus f(A) \ne \emptyset$ or $A \setminus g(B) \ne \emptyset$ then $A$ and $B$ must be infinite sets.

Answer (score 0):

The OP writes

> Then I assigned exactly one point to each of $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},A_{4},$ and $A_{5}$. I repeated the process with $B$ and assigned exactly one point to each $B_{1},B_{2},B_{3},B_{4},$ and $B_{5}$

This 'proof probing' can be actualized by taking a concrete example and 'running it thru' the proof diagram.

Let $f: \Bbb Z^{>0} \to \Bbb Z^{<0}$ be given by

$\quad f: m \mapsto -(m+1)$

Let $g: \Bbb Z^{<0} \to \Bbb Z^{>0}$ be given by

$\quad g: m \mapsto 1-m$

So we have two injective mappings and we set

$\quad B_1 = \Bbb Z^{<0} \setminus f\bigr(\Bbb Z^{>0}\bigr) = \{-1\}$

Here is the corresponding diagram

[image]

and

$\quad A_0 = \{1,3,5,\dots\}$

$\quad B_0 = \{-2,-4,-6,\dots\}$

The bijection $h:\Bbb Z^{>0} \to \Bbb Z^{<0}$ is given by

$$
h(n)=\begin{cases}g^{-1}(n)&n \text{ is even}\\
f(n)&n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

---

Examining the OP's diagram proof found in the book, we start by setting $B_1$ to all the elements of $B$ that $f$ 'misses'. The recursive $g^{-1}$ chain  correspondence

$\quad A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},A_{4},$
$\quad B_{1},B_{2},B_{3},B_{4},$

'squeezes out' the problem, so that when you get to the

$\quad f: A_0 \to B_0$

step you know that $f$ is surjective since $B_0 \cap B_1 = \emptyset$.